# Using an Interface as an Abstract Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I want to reuse code as much as possible, I'm thinking in implementing autowiring so I can have dynamic beans getting called by Services names, some of them might have default functionality across all classes that implements ICountry interface.

```
public interface ICountry {

//some services

default String methodOne(String var) {
//some large implementation, metrics, etc.
}}
```

---

```
@Service("mexico")
Public class MexicoServiceImpl implements ICountry {}
```

---

```
@Service("canada")
Public class CanadaServiceImpl implements ICountry {}
```

---

```
@Autowire
private Map<String,ICountry> fooImplementation;

//some method
fooImplementation.get(dto.getCountry()).methodOne()
```

I plan to implement the whole class funcionality with default and private methods inside the interface, so only the implementations that need a different behaviour,validations, etc, can always override and implement extra private methods if they need to in their class.

Importing different services of my application, I would send as an argument the country so the default method knows what country it's implementing for in case that country is not overriding the default method, so I can differentiate metrics.

Is this a bad practice? I'm choosing Interface over abstract classes so I can autowire and use dynamically bean services.

Comment: If its bad practice, only your specific scenario can tell. But to me it looks like your implementing classes should instead be in data. Is the variations between your country classes really so large that they require different methods?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer they will use mostly the same default methods, but some of them might require to override for country specific extra steps. the implementations should look more or less empty, because they will mostly use the default methods. I wanted to separate services by country so the code can be country specific in their respective folders and easy to read/find by other programmers instead of having multiple "ifs" inside the Class doing the work for all countries.

Comment: You could also make your data model a bit more complex and change the code to use that extra data. You never give examples of what will be country dependent, so it is hard to give you better advise.

Comment: Your main limitation is that interfaces cannot have fields. For those, you need a class. If that's not an issue, this seems fine.